# Trouble getting object from parsed JSON output

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm playing around with the twitter API and i'm trying to parse the json output. However somehow i'm doing something wrong and I'm not getting what I would like to get.

In this case i'm writing in PHP. Started looping thru the array and screen_name and text are working accordingly.

```
foreach ($statuses as $obj) {

  $screen_name  =   filter_var($obj->user->screen_name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $text         =   filter_var($obj->text, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $urls         =   filter_var($obj->entities->urls->url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
}
```

the JSON array output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'created_at' => 'Fri Oct 07 15:31:01 +0000 2016',
     'text' => 'test',
     'entities' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'hashtags' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'text' => '30Under30',
           'indices' => 
          array (
            0 => 36,
            1 => 46,
          ),
        )),
      ),
       'symbols' => 
      array (
      ),
       'user_mentions' => 
      array (
      ),
       'urls' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'url' => 'https://Forbes.com',
           'expanded_url' => 'https://twitter.com/i/web/status/784415744427687936',
           'display_url' => 'twitter.com/i/web/status/7…',
           'indices' => 
          array (
            0 => 117,
            1 => 140,
          ),
        )),
      ),
    )),
     'source' => 'Sprinklr',
     'in_reply_to_screen_name' => NULL,
     'user' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'id' => 91478624,
       'screen_name' => 'test',
       'url' => 'http://Forbes.com',
       'entities' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'url' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'urls' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            stdClass::__set_state(array(
               'url' => 'http://Forbes.com',
               'expanded_url' => 'http://forbes.com',
               'display_url' => 'forbes.com',
               'indices' => 
              array (
                0 => 0,
                1 => 22,
              ),
            )),
          ),
        )),
         'description' => 
        stdClass::__set_state(array(
           'urls' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            stdClass::__set_state(array(
               'url' => 'http://Forbes.com',
               'expanded_url' => 'http://Forbes.com',
               'display_url' => 'Forbes.com',
               'indices' => 
              array (
                0 => 28,
                1 => 48,
              ),
            )),
          ),
        )),
      )),
       'protected' => false,
       'notifications' => false,
    )),
     'geo' => NULL,
     'lang' => 'en',
  )),
)
```

Comment: Would be nice to have an example of what you want as result. My guess just pass second parameter as true `json_decode($string, true)`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I want the first `'url' => 'https://Forbes.com',` parameter. I think it around line 32. To me it looks like the path is entities->urls->url. However this does not work

Comment: `urls` is an array, so you need `$obj->entities->urls[0]->url`

Comment: ah works. Thanks.

Comment: But why do I not have to specify the array number in the $obj part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `urls` is an array, you need to index it.

```
$urls         =   filter_var($obj->entities->urls[0]->url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```